# Access flashbag form AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator

Tags: symfony, authentication

Symfony version: 5.1.8

When using a form authenticator `AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator`, the method `onAuthenticationSuccess` output a redirection.
After this redirection, I would like to display a message of success for the user who successfully logged in.

The use of the flashbag from the authenticator would have been nice for this use case, and that's what I have implemented through injecting `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface` to make use of the service `session.flash_bag`.
Combined with:

```
$this->flashbag->set('login_successfull', 'message_login_form_valid');
```

It works.

But after upgrading to Symfony 5.1, I discovered this deprecation:

```
User Deprecated: Since symfony/framework-bundle 5.1: The "session.flash_bag" service is deprecated, use "$session->getFlashBag()" instead.
```

I am trying to solve this deprecation by using `$flashbag = $request->getSession()->getBag('flash')`, but I can't make it work as there are no methods on `$flashbag` to set a message (only `getName`, `getStorageKey`, `clear` or `initialize`).

I have also tryed to inject the autowired `session` service available, but it comes from `SessionInterface` that doesn't let you retrieve and set the flashbag in the same way I mentioned above.

Maybe I don't see things correctly, do you have any advise to solve this use case?
I have though of dropping the idea of using the flashbag for this, but I can't see a nice way to pass information after a redirection?

Comment: FlashBagInterface has both add and set.  Perhaps your IDE is getting confused?  Session::getFlashBag returns a FlashBagInterface.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `$this->addFlash` method of the `AbstractController` you could find service that is used by default to add new flash message. So you code should be looked like this:

```
$this->session->getFlashBag()->add($type, $message);
```

where `$this->session` property is instance of: `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface`

Comment: It's actually a bit interesting, to me at least, that SessionInterface does not have a getFlashBag method defined.  Session does but not the interface.  I suspect that by type hinting against SessionInterface, the IDE does not know the correct return type for getFlashBag.  Surprised it does not complain about it.

Comment: That's because SessionInterface has only one "implementor" and PhpStorm could automatically detect implementor's methods. So there is no warnings. But If you create another instance of SessionInterface PhpStorm would warn you about it

Answer (score 1):

Other answers were not working for me.

Symfony 6 onwards, now `Request` and `RequestStack` both Classes have `getSession()` method.

one can use flashbag via `$request->getSession()->getFlashBag()`

e.g.

```
public function detectRequiredReport(RequestStack $request){         
   $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'message');           
}
```

Comment: This helped me when trying to get the flashbag in a custom service. It seems you can't inject `Request` into services but you can inject `RequestStack`, meaning you can use the `getCurrentRequest()` method on it and subsequently the `getSession()` and `getFlashBag()` methods.

As @Cerad pointed out however, the `SessionInterface` does not have a `getFlashBag()` method even though it exists on the `Session` object, so that's something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would post this here just because it's a bit of a mystery.

SessionInterface::getFlashBag does not exist.

Session::getFlashBag does exist and returns a FlashBagInterface containing add/set methods.

The strange thing is that PHPStorm does not complain about using a method that is not defined in the interface.

```
class SomeService
{
    private SessionInterface $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }
    public function doSomething()
    {
        // For some reason PHPStorm accepts this
        /** @var FlashBagInterface $flashBag */
        $flashBag = $this->session->getFlashBag();
        $flashBag->add('flash','me');
    }
}
```

The above code works without warnings even though getFlashBag is not listed in the code assistance menu.  I had to know it was there and type in the full name.  And even though PHPStorm knows the method returns a FlashBagInterface, I still had to add the var mapping to get methods to appear on $flashBag.  All very confusing.

I expect that the session interface issue will be fixed in the next release.

Turns out that there are several github issues on this dataing back several years.  Decision was made not to implement the 'fix'.  Mostly BC problems.

Comment: It now works perfectly with your solution and the deprecation has been removed from symfony toolbar. Hope this behavior will be corrected one day. Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 0):

add this bib in control

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
```

taper this message in your funtion :

```
$session = new Session();
$session->start();

// add flash messages
$session->getFlashBag()->add(
    'success',
    'Note est  bein cree'
);
$session->getFlashBag()->add(
    'warning',
    'Your config file is writable, it should be set read-only'
);
```

and this code  in your page twig :

```
{% for message in app.flashes("success") %}
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ message }}
      </div>
{% endfor%}
```

in plus info visit site web of symfony:

> https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#flash-messages